# how to concatenate with parameter in azure data factory / passing dynamic table names in source query

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created in pipeline parameter and i wanted to pass array of tables to perform multiple copy activity. BUT before that i am testing with only one table as a parameter.
I have created below query in expression (sink side of copy activity).
(Please note i am copying from synapse to synapse (from one schema to another))

```
@concat('select * from DW_GL.',pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table,' where updated_on >',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,' and updated_on <=',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new)
```

My table is in the schema "DW_GL" so i tried to remove it from above expression and still its not working.

i am getting error:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Parse error at line: 1, column: 75: Incorrect syntax near '03'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Parse error at line: 1, column: 75: Incorrect syntax near '03'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=103010,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=103010,State=1,Message=Parse error at line: 1, column: 75: Incorrect syntax near '03'.,},],'

i tried removing empty white spaces from expression .
also tried to use direct parameter without concatenate as '@{pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table}' still not worked.

Comment: Can you also please add a static version of the query you are expecting in your question meaning the actual query that would be executed on database

Comment: select * from DW_GL.my_table where UPDATED_ON > '@{activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value}' and UPDATED_ON <= '@{activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new}'

Comment: those dates in where conditions are coming from lookup and my pipeline works when the table name is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is because this concat statement does not include single quotes (') around the date values. You need to use '' to include them, which translates to ''' to end (or begin) a string with ', and '''' to insert JUST a single ':

```
@concat('select * from DW_GL.',pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table,' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new, '''')
```

Comment: And it works! Thank you so much for your help in solving this issue.

Comment: now, i changed the pipeline parameter from string to array and passed 2 tables in values ["table1","table2"]. but i am getting another error "concat does not have an overload that supports the arguments given:(StringLiteral,Array.........)" . To resolve this i tried to convert parameter to string like following query: @concat('select * from DW_GL.',string(pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table),' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new, ''''). but still another error:

Comment: ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'table' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'

Comment: This is a different error and problem, you should post a new question with those details.

Answer (score 0):

Below query can also work :

```
select * from DW_GL.@{pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table} where updated_on > '@{activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value}' and updated_on <=' @{activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new}'
```