# array of input tables as pipeline parameter

Tags: azure-data-factory

With Continuation from the question which is already resolved :
[how to concatenate with parameter in azure data factory / passing dynamic table names in source query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996159/how-to-concatenate-with-parameter-in-azure-data-factory-passing-dynamic-table)

i have created a pipeline parameter and passing array of tables to perform multiple copy (incremental) operation using control table (watermark table). i have successfully tested the pipeline with single table as a parameter which is of type string. However when i am changing the parameter from String to Array and passing 2 tables ["table1","table2"] i am getting error as:

- "concat does not have an overload that supports the arguments given:(StringLiteral,Array.........)" *

However i have updated the parameterized query in following way (using converion to string).

`@concat('select * from DW_GL.',string(pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table),' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new, '''')`

i am getting error now as follows:

*ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'table' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,' –*

However i have updated the parameterized query in following way (using converion to string).

`@concat('select * from DW_GL.',string(pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table),' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new, '''')`

Comment: Can you clarify these: pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table is the parameter you have changed from string to array. And have you tried your query with static values instead of dynamic content first?

Comment: Provide the static query that you tried. If the pipeline parameter is an array and you want to operate each table in the array separately, then you might want to use for loop to iterate and use the table value as required through iterations

Comment: Hi, Yes, pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table is the parameter and i changed it from from string to array. later i used string(pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table) to convert it to string. Do you mean instead of array, i should use foreach?

Comment: You want to apply the same process (the one which you used for 1 table) to each of the table name present in your array right? If this is the case, then yes, use a for each loop to iterate through this array parameter and use @item() anywhere you are using the parameter inside for each loop

Comment: my goal is to incrementally copy several tables one after another OR in parallel. can this be achieved using parameter Array?

Comment: You already have configured the incremental copy for one table successfully (string parameter). So, to do it with array parameter, you can simply use for each as given in the solution below (one after another). All you have to do is use the pipeline activity configuration that worked for single table inside for each as indicated in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You have an array of tables, and trying to use it in the same query just by replacing string with an array of tables directly.
- If you want to apply the process which worked for each table separately, then you can use a for each loop. Lets say I have the following array of table names:

[image]

- Now I have configured the for each loop where I have given the items value as the above parameter. Inside for each I have taken a sample script. I have used a query similar to the one given below:

```
@concat('select * from DW_GL.',item(),' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.id,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.id, '''')
```

[image]

- Now within this for each, you have to keep all the activities that you have used in the case of single table name for parameter (string).
- If you are trying to do it simultaneously, then you can check what query is being implemented in the debug input of script activity. Giving same query as yours would build the query in the following way:

[image]

- To select multiple tables at a time, you can use `join()` instead of directly converting it to string. Use the following dynamic content instead:

```
@concat('select * from DW_GL.',join(pipeline().parameters.p_param_input_table,',DW_GL.'),' where updated_on > ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value,''' and updated_on <= ''',activity('Old_Lookup1').output.firstRow.date_value_new, '''')
```

[image]

**NOTE:** My activity failed as I just wanted to demonstrate what query will be executed based on the given dynamic content. Use accordingly.